# Does anyone know when/in what work Dedekind introduced the concept of a Euclidean domain?

Tags: math-history, euclidean-domain

I've found Dedekind referenced as the progenitor of the concept but I cannot find the source for the concept.

Comment: Maybe Dedekind's *Supplements* to Dirichlet's [Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie (1863)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorlesungen_%C3%BCber_Zahlentheorie).

Comment: See Dedekind's Supplements X and XI in which he begins to develop the theory of ideals.

Comment: It was Dirichlet who observed that if a system of numbers admits a Euclidean algorithm, then unique factorization holds. The idea of rings and domains came much later with Fraenkel and Emmy Noether.

Comment: Would you happen to know where Noether and Fraenkel develop the concept of a Euclidean domain?

Comment: @William: They developed the concept of a ring, not a Euclidean ring.  So if you emphasize the ring in Euclidean ring that means the idea was introduced after Dedekind. If you emphasize onle "Euclidean" then it was Dirichlet.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I am more interested in "Euclidean ring" than I am in "Euclidean" or "ring", if that makes sense.